# Is there a system role to allow viewing definition of all objects in a database?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to request that a global group by given sufficient access to a production database in order to perform support of applications that use the database. I am trying to identify what specific rights I need to request.

in order to perform a query against all of the tables, I would like to request `db_datareader` access. i'd like to avoid the maintenance of making sure that the global group has `SELECT` and `VIEW DEF` access to all objects. I know that `db_datareader rights`, if approved, will give a user full `SELECT` rights to all tables. Is there a counterpart Role that grants rights to view teh definition of all tables, stored procedure, views, etc?

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [your database]
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader', '[your user name]'
```

Comment: Just to make sure: Does this give the user read access to all objects including stored procedures or is DDL_ADMIN rights needed?

Answer (score 0):

Define "sufficient access to a production database"

As a DBA, I would not give any DDL admin or any type of access that allows users to alter schema on the fly, that's a recipe for a disaster and will make your DBA work harder. A DBA must and should be able to help on performance issue and change production schemas after proper testing. You really do not want to change production schema without testing 1st.

Having said that, if user(s) want limited access to troubleshoot performance issues (this actually can make your life easier) they may need any of these:

- VIEW DATABASE STATE
- VIEW SERVER STATE

Those two, allow access to DMVs, which are useful to pinpoint performance issues and how queries are running.

SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, etc, are normal though. If your database objects (tables, views, sprocs) do not require granular permissions, I would use any of the default database role and put the user or users inside.

Permissions to run store procedures would be EXECUTE.